# how to draw a bitmap larger than the canvas in android

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap

I am developing an application in which the preview of the camera is displayed constantly. When the user wants, he takes a picture with takePicture () and stores it in a bitmap picture to draw it later.

The problem is that the canvas is drawing the preview all the time, and when you draw the bitmap of the image made ​​previously, the canvas draws it incorrectly. I think it's because the bitmap has higher resolution than the canvas because the bitmap has the resolution of the camera and not canvas.

How I can fix this?. I need to get properly draw the bitmap into the canvas.

Thank you

Comment: Did you fix this problem? I am having the same..

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have the bitmap what you need to do is draw the bitmap on the canvas, but before you do that scale the canvas so that the full bitmap is small compared to that. It'll still preview correctly but it'll make it smaller than the full sized image.